# Case when, make return different values in different columns

Tags: sql

Been too long since i used this...

Problem is, i need to update 3 columns based on 1 value:
So, if value = 10, then x=1,y=0,z=0, if value = 20, then x=0,y=1,z=0, if value = 30 ,then x=0,y=0,z=1, if value = 40 ,then x=1,y=1,z=0, else x=0,y=0,z=0

Trying to write this as a case when and got me stumped.

```
select *, 
case when value=10 then 1 else 0 end as x,
case when value=10 then 0 else 1 end as y,
case when value=10 then 0 else 1 end as z,
case when value=20 then 0 else 1 end as x,
case when value=20 then 1 else 0 end as y,
case when value=20 then 0 else 1 end as z,
--etc--
from table_1
```

Comment: What database are you using? Some SQL dialects can handle this better than others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put the condition by column
x =1 when value =10 or 40 else 0,y =1 when value =20 or 40 else 0,z =1 when value =30 else 0

```
select *, 
case when value in (10,40)  then 1 else 0 end as x,
case when value in (20,40) then 1 else 0 end as y,
case when value=30 then 1 else 0 end as z
--etc--
from table_1
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL you'd have one case for each column.

```
select
  case value
  when 10 then 1
  when 20 then 0
  when 30 then 0
  when 40 then 1
  else 0
  end as x,

  case value
  when 10 then 0
  when 20 then 1
  when 30 then 0
  when 40 then 1
  else 0
  end as y,

  case value
  when 10 then 0
  when 20 then 0
  when 30 then 1
  when 40 then 0
  else 0
  end as z
```